# Touch events not sent to a new view added with addSubview

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, touchesmoved, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have an area of my screen on which I want to recognize a long press. I use a UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Once the long press event happens, I show a custom UIView that has a `touchesMoved` method, by adding it as a subview. This custom UIView is added right in the center of where the long press event happened, it is right under my finger.

Problem: If I'm continuously holding my finger after the long press, the `touchesMoved` on the custom UIView is not called. Only when I lift my finger and touch again is the `touchesMoved` method recognized.

Any possible solutions? I believe the problem is that when the touch started, it originated from the underlying view. Even though I add a new UIView on top of the hierarchy and move my finger over it, it is not recognized, ie `touchesMoved` is not called because the view went into the hierarchy already after the touches have began.

I've tried a couple of things to cancel the long press gesture recognizer but nothing seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try adding touchesMoved on your parent view and call public methods of the child and do what needs to be done? Just thinking aloud.

Comment: @GurtejSingh I guess I could, but I want my custom UIView to be library-like. Ie, you should be able to plug-and-play it, the parent shouldn't be responsible for passing touch events down to it. Anyways, thanks for the input.

Comment: Absolutely. I understand. Hope we find an answer soon :)

Comment: Try setting the parent view.clipToBounds = NO and run it. If your subview is outside of the frame of the parent view, it will not get the touch events. Setting clipToBounds = NO will make your subview disappear if this is the case.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ?